# Error when using acro: 'long-short' of type 'acro-first' is (xtemplate) unknown

Tags: texlive, acro, xtemplate

I just switched from overleaf to using vim for latex and executing everything on the commandline.
My code previously compiled without errors in Overleaf, but now i am getting a problem with acro.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{cond}{
    short=Cond.\@,
    long=Condition,
    first-style=long-short,
}

\begin{document}
\ac{cond}
\end{document}
```

I execute `pdflatex test.tex` and get the following errors:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acro/acro.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-abspage.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acro/acro.definitions.tex))
(./test.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations-basic-dictio
nary-english.trsl)

! Package xtemplate Error: The instance 'long-short' of type 'acro-first' is
(xtemplate)                unknown.
```

I deleted and reinstalled texlive, I am using Ubuntu 22.04.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The version of `acro` used on OverLeaf is version 3.2, you could downgrade to that version of `acro` and see if the error persists. On Windows 10 with Tex Live 2021 and `acro` version 3.5 your code compiles fine for me. `acro` is [currently on version 3.8](https://ftpmirror1.infania.net/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro-manual.pdf), which I guess is what yours is? If you put `\listfiles` in your preamble, comment out `\DeclareAcronym` and run your file it will output the version in the log.

Comment: You may wish to consider installing ["vanilla" TeX Live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/106162) independently of the Ubuntu package manager, the Ubuntu-packaged version you show here lags several years which is the root cause of your error.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu packaged TeX Live you have installed is TeX Live 2019 which almost certainly contains acro v2 (given release dates and noting `/acro/acro.definitions.tex` is loaded in the log), rather than acro v3.

In acro 2.x the `long-short` first-style does not exist (exactly as the error indicates), you probably want the `default` first-style which, unsurprisingly, is the default and does not need to be specified (as is `long-short` for acro v3), unless a different `first-style` is set at the global level.

In order to access the version-specific documentation for an installed package you can run `texdoc acro` in the terminal, searching for `first-style` brings the allowed `first-style`s.